# Is it normal that exporting a json file to csv through pandas is taking forever?

Tags: python, json, pandas, csv

I tried to export a json file to a csv file using pandas but the operation last for hours without ending. I'm pretty sure the code is not the issue, but rather the way I'm exporting the data. Is it possible that the json file is too heavy ?

Here is the code:

```
import json 
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

search_date = datetime(2019, 8, 4)

nextSequence = timedelta(days=9)

path = 'C:/Users/coppe/dox/Drivy/' 

new_car_list = []

while search_date <= datetime(2019, 12, 17):
    if search_date == datetime(2019, 12, 8):
        pass
    else:
        file = str(datetime.date(search_date)) + '/' + str(datetime.date(search_date)) + '_final'+ '.json'
        with open(path + file) as json_file:  
            cars = json.load(json_file)    
            json_file.close()
        for car in cars:
            new_car_list.append(car)
        search_date += nextSequence

with open(path + 'getaround_final.json', 'w') as outfile:  
    json.dump(new_car_list, outfile)   

pd.read_json(path + 'getaround_final.json').to_csv(path + 'getaround_final.csv', index=False)
```

Comment: How big is the json file?

Comment: this will make infinite loop at `pass`.   when you `pass`, the date stays as 2019-12-8 and it will fall into if-pass over and over.  you are missing to increment date in this if block.   I don't think you are reaching to the data exporting line.

Comment: Thank you Emma, I just had to move the `search_date += nextSequence` and now it operates correctly.